# Add vertical arrow on Quartil

Tags: arrows

I wanted to make picture looks like this.

[image]

What I have done so far,

```
\documenclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
$$
\underbrace{2\quad 4\quad 6\quad 6}_{\textrm{empat nilai}} \quad \underset{Q_2}{7}  \quad  \underbrace{9\quad 9\quad 11\quad 12}_{\textrm{empat nilai}}
$$
\end{document}
```

the output

[image]

I want to add vertical arrow pointing the number for Q1, Q2 or Q3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `\substack`.

*Unrelated*: don't use `$$ … $$` for displayed equation in LaTeX: – this is a plain TeX construct, and it can result in a bad vertical spacing. Use `\[ … \]` instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \underbrace{2\quad 4\quad 6\quad 6}_{\textrm{empat nilai}} \quad \underset{\substack{\uparrow\\Q_2}}{7} \quad \underbrace{9\quad 9\quad 11\quad 12}_{\textrm{empat nilai}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would just draw the whole thing with Ti*k*Z rather than messing around with arrows from some fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\[
 \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={calligraphic brace,mirror,raise=0.5ex}]
  \path[start chain=A going right,node distance=1em]
   foreach \x in {2,4,6,6,7,9,9,11,12}{node[on chain]{$\x$}};
  \draw[decorate,thick] (A-1.south west) -- node[below=1ex] {empat nilai}
    (A-4.south east); 
  \draw[decorate,thick] (A-6.south west) -- node[below=1ex] {empat nilai}
    (A-9.south east); 
  \draw[latex-] (A-5.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) node[below]{$Q_2$};  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\[
 \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={calligraphic brace,mirror,raise=0.5ex}]
  \path[start chain=A going right,node distance=1em]
   foreach \x in {2,4,6,6,7,9,9,11,12}{node[on chain]{$\x$}};
  \foreach \x in {1,3,6,8} 
  {\draw[decorate,thick] (A-\x.south west) --   (A-\the\numexpr\x+1\relax.south east); }
  \draw[latex-] ($(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.south)$) -- ++ (0,-1em) node[below]{$Q_1$};  
  \draw[latex-] (A-5.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) node[below]{$Q_2$};  
  \draw[latex-] ($(A-7.south)!0.5!(A-8.south)$) -- ++ (0,-1em) node[below]{$Q_3$};  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With a friendly syntax (but unfriendly code, but, hey, it works!).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\quartils}{ O{1em} m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \masrosid_quartil:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\quartilD}{ o m }
 {
  \masrosid_quartil_D:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\quartilQ}{ m m }
 {
  \masrosid_quartil_Q:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\dim_new:N \l__masrosid_quartil_sep_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \masrosid_quartil:nn
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \D \quartilD
  \cs_set_eq:NN \Q \quartilQ
  \dim_set:Nn \l__masrosid_quartil_sep_dim { #1 }
  #2
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \masrosid_quartil_D:nn
 {
  {
   \underbrace
    {
     \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #2 }
     \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \skip_horizontal:N \l__masrosid_quartil_sep_dim }
    }
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #1 } { \sb{\textup{#1}} }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \masrosid_quartil_Q:nn
 {
  \underset{ \substack { \big\uparrow \\ Q\sb{#1}\mathstrut } }
   {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
     { \skip_horizontal:N \l__masrosid_quartil_sep_dim }
     {
      \skip_horizontal:N \l__masrosid_quartil_sep_dim
      #2
      \skip_horizontal:N \l__masrosid_quartil_sep_dim
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\quartils{ \D[empat nilai]{2,4,6,6} \Q{2}{7} \D[empat nilai]{9,9,11,12} }
\]

\[
\quartils{ \D{2,4} \Q{1}{} \D{6,6} \Q{2}{7} \D{9,9} \Q{3}{} \D{11,12} }
\]

\end{document}
```

The parts to be underbraced are given as arguments to `\D` (for “data”), with an optional argument for the explanatory text. The quartils are denoted by `\Q`, where the first argument is the quartil number, whereas the second argument is the data (if empty, the spacing will be right).

[image]

The command `\quartils` also accepts an optional argument, default `1em`, for the spacing between entries. If you call

```
\quartils[2em]{ \D{2,4} \Q{1}{} \D{6,6} \Q{2}{7} \D{9,9} \Q{3}{} \D{11,12} }
```

the output would be

[image]